# Confusion with Instantiating Custom Object array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, instantiation

I have a Class called CrabWorld that holds all the actors in the scene. I have an array of Lobster()'s that I initialize when called by the constructor.  I have a simple for-loop that loops through the array and instantiates each individual Lobster.

```
public class CrabWorld extends World {

public Lobster[] lobsters = new Lobster[5];
public Crab playerCrab = new Crab();

private Counter score = new Counter("Score: ");
private int numbOfWorms = 0;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class CrabWorld.
 * 
 */
    public CrabWorld(){

        super(560, 560, 1); 

        for (int i = 0; i < lobsters.length; i++){
            Lobster lobsters[i] = new Lobster();
        }

        prepare();
    }
}
```

So this is what I originally had, however I would get an error saying "expected ']'"   It doesn't complile, BUT when I delete the [i] from the lobsters variable, It compiled easily with no errors. This is where the confustion sets in, for I was under the impression the only way that you instantiate objects within an array was to loop over them and reference to them by i.  I've tried sever different combinations of lobsters.  I.E leaving the the Lobster typecast, removing the "[i]".  Neither of these worked, and I was curious to see if anyone could point out the problem, that for all that it's worth, I need to get it done...

Note: the prepare() method is already defined later in the script. (super is an @override).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Lobster lobsters[i] = new Lobster();
```

should be

```
lobsters[i] = new Lobster();
```

The `lobsters` array was already declared, so you only have to assign `Lobster` instances to each index of the array.

Answer (score 1):

In for loop, just use:

```
lobsters[i] = new Lobster();
```